# Where does the expression "to shine someone on" come from? And does it have racist origins?

Tags: verbs, idioms, offensive-language

Someone suggested to me that the idiom "to shine someone on" is racist in origin.

I'm not talking about *shine on* or *shine* or any of those other uses. What I'm referring to is *shining someone on* meaning in either of its meanings listed here, but mainly the first one:

> **shine (one) on**
>
> 1. To deceive one or to tell one a lie, especially in order to deflect or avoid responsibility for something.
>    *He told me he hadn't touched a drop of alcohol, but I think he was shining me on.*
>    *Don't shine us on, Marty. We know you're the one who screwed up the accounts!*
> 2. To insult, provoke, or aggravate one.
>    *After the neighbors complained about my Christmas lights, I decided to shine them on a bit by adding even more to my house.*
>    *If you really want to shine him on, you should bring his sister to the Christmas party as your date.
>    Don't shine the immigration officer on, or you very well might get booted out of the country!*
>    <sub>[TFD Online, Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shine+someone+on)</sub>

I can't find any etymology for this. I'd like to know when and how it came about because if its roots are racist (*shine* being an [offensive term](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/shine) [for a Black person](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=shine)), I want to avoid it.

Comment: I can infer why *shine* ***might*** be offensive in some contexts, but for the sake of clarity, you should add the reason for it to your question rather than just assuming everybody thinks the same way. I also don't think that anybody would find it offensive in *every* context. So what would make *shine (one) on* more potentially racist than *shine a light*?

Comment: @Jason: See my final sentence.  I give the reason there.

Comment: The final sentence doesn't explain anything. All it says is that it's an offensive term for a Black person. There is no explanation for why that should be the case. Can you support that claim?

Comment: @Jason: [**shine** 8. Offensive Slang Used as a disparaging term for a black person.](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/shine)

Comment: Also [Derogatory meaning "black person" is from 1908 (perhaps from glossiness of skin or, on another guess, from frequent employment as shoeshines).](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=shine).

Comment: Also I read that Stephen King said his original title for *The Shining* was "The Shine" and he was flummoxed when his editor told him what that implied (especially since one of his characters with ESP was Black).

Comment: Interesting. I've never encountered its derogatory sense before, and was only making some assumptions about why it might be so. Even more interesting is that not even Etymology Online knows exactly why it's derogatory—instead using words like "perhaps" and "guess." You should add some of those references to the question for context.

Comment: “*Shine: in uses meaning a black person [the reflection of a blue-black skin; as used in W.I. the term refers to someone with a very dark, smooth complexion and has no derog. connotations].*” https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/h7oshmy —- I think the term “shine” meaning black person and the expression “shine someone on” are unrelated.

Comment: Can we equate shine with polish, as in apple polishing, and thus BS? Or similarly with polishing a tool (jerking me off), and thus wasting my time?

Comment: @Sven Yargs: I would very much love to know your insights on this one.

Comment: For some reason, Spanish and Portuguese speakers keep on and on about "etymology" when what they really mean is: "the origin of a phrase".

Answer (score 2):

It's a hard phrase to search for.  A Google N-Gram search for "shine him on" offers a number of hits in accord with the definitions in the questions.

In the following, the phrase is described as an "old theatrical expression."  In this case an actor says the script writer recognizes the script's weaknesses, and thus the actor doesn't have to "shine him on:"

https://www.google.com/books/edition/All_His_Jazz/5Vr0l7Ux2OAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22shine+him+on%22&pg=PT191&printsec=frontcover

All His Jazz: The Life And Death Of Bob Fosse
By Martin Gottfried (1990)

Answer (score 1):

According to GDoS “shine” in *shine someone on* and other related expressions is a euphemism for *shit* (a US black usage).

> [Shine someone on](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/sf43nvy#dbdga4i) (v.) (also put someone on (the) shine, shine it on, shine on someone) [euph. [shit](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/2jwxjqa#sn1) n. (1)]
> (US black) to ignore, to disdain.
> 1968

> - 1968    [US]    ‘Sl. of Watts’ in Current Sl. III:2 41: *Shine it on, v. Forget about it; don’t pay it any attention.*
> - 1969    [US]    Cressey & Ward Delinquency, Crime, and Social Process 808: *If an initiate arrives on the scene and presents an image of being ‘rowdy,’ ‘lame,’ or ‘uncool,’ he is immediately ‘put on the shine’ (shunned).*

Comment: Can you explain how "shine someone on" acquired this pejorative meaning? I read your answer twice but I can't seem to understand how it explains that. I understand "shine" as a non-pejorative word and has very positive connotations but don't understand how it acquired this pejorative meaning.

Comment: @Melancholy - shine is used as a  euphemism for shit, a US black usage.  “*Shit someone on, shit on someone, put someone on the shit.....*” probably because of their opposite meanings and assonance.

Answer (score 1):

in our (white) working class neighborhood we used this to imply that someone was being duped, or ignored, or deceived in some way.

"He said he would, do it, but you know he's just shining us"

"if you can't come and get me, just stop shining then, I'll find another ride"

"I asked her to come, but I guess she said "shine on that!" after I was gone.

Just my opinion, but any racist origin could be the stereotypical newsstand shoe shiner, convincing a less wary victim to "sit down, sit down it will only take a second boss"and with enough spit, and polish, and hustle,  an old boot might briefly pass as new. The shine won't last and you've wasted a nickle.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it merely offers a personal opinion that confirms the expression's (already confirmed) usage.

Answer (score 0):

It is black vernacular in America. I think it refers to smiling at someone when they're a clueless dipshit and you just tolerate it for the duration of the interchange.
It could also refer to the smile of the shoe-shine toward his customers, but that's a much earlier reference. It could be the root.
It basically is about a power interchange with a racist or privileged white person.

Comment: Please show some earlier usage to support your explanation.

Comment: In the southern US, this phrase is used by everyone regardless of skin color.

Answer (score 0):

Shine can come from the german/jiddish "der Schein" resp. "der Anschein" which translates to "its superficial appearance" with a connotation that what's behind the appearance is not what the appearance suggested. "Der Schein kann trügen" = "appearances can be deceiving" or "der Schein trügt" = "of deceiving appearance"

Comment: Axel, do you have any evidence to support your suggestion that this **specific** expression and meaning comes from German/Yiddish? It seems unnecessary to point out the connection with German, given that the English verb *shine* and the German verb *scheinen* [share a common Proto-Germanic root](https://www.etymonline.com/word/shine#etymonline_v_23402). Please note that EL&U is a bit different from other Q&A sites: we're looking for *authoritative answers supported by evidence*. For further guidance, see [answer] and take our **[Tour]**. :-)

Answer (score -2):

Although the term itself may not have a racist origin, use of the word "shine" could be construed as racist, depending on the context. In U.S. urban cities (usually transportation hubs), some men and boys would shine shoes to make money. Often, they would be Black males. They would be called (and respond to) "Shoe-shine" or just "Shine".
While making an honest buck was fine, the real issue here was its public image: a man (usually Caucasian and middle-class) sitting in a high-perched chair and getting his shoes shined by a Black man or boy on his knees. The image is considered subservient or servile, referencing a slave-like position and, therefore, a racist connotation.

Please understand my contribution here is merely conjecture and speculation. I have not done any formal research or read anything definitive.

Comment: This site seeks definitive and sourced answers, not conjecture and speculation.